Who is responsible to remove the landing gear pins in an airliner?
On a recent flight the airplane had to turn back, because the nose gear could not be retracted. Upon landing inspection it was found that the landing gear pin had not been removed.

Who is ultimately responsible to notice something like that?
Are there sensors indicating to the cockpit if the pins are present or not?
Are the pins required for push-back? In that case the pilots could not have spotted it during walk-around, correct?

In short, how can something like this happen and who is to blame?

Who: Why does the headset man not get on the tractor?, sensor: What item is a pushback operator holding up after pushback?, and in genereal: How is the pushback tug connected to the airliner?

Normally there are no indications pins are installed in the cockpit. Forgetting to take them out isn't really a safety issue, more of an expense.
Ultimately the Pilot In Command is responsible, as one of the items to check on the walkaround is that pins are removed, whether by ground crew or the pilot doing the walkaround. They are normally stowed on board, so at some point the PIC will need to confirm that all safety pins are removed and are aboard the aircraft.
On the CRJ200 there were 3 pins for the main gears, one for the nose gear doors (because they were hydraulically operated) and one for the Air Driven Generator (right beside the nose gear bay), and whomever did the walkaround would present to the cockpit with a hand full of pins and say "five pins", before stowing them. It was up to the PIC in the end to confirm all 5 pins were there.
I know of a Global Express that departed Montreal with the nose gear pin installed. Rather than return and land overweight or fly around burning off fuel just to return, the crew continued to destination with the gear down and speed limited to 250kt. It was likely the First Officer who did the walkaround and forgot it, and he/she certainly would have been in the dog house, but ultimately the Captain is on the hook.

In our Boeing 737s the gear pins are stored in a rack at the front the electronics panel and are checked as part of the Before Start Checklist “gear pins……….1,2,3 removed.” We physically count them at the start of our flying day. (They aren’t part of the transit before start checklist).

Why continuing to destination with gear down might be a bad idea.

@Bianfable The Global crew made all the calcs and decided continuing wasn't a safety issue. IIRC it had the mains retracted with just the nose gear extended.

Thank you, John! So does that mean that there is no pin installed during the push-back? Otherwise how would the removed pin be put into the cockpit? In this case it was a transatlantic flight, so I am sure it made sense to return to the airport.

It's possible some airplane could have a pin that has to be removed after the push-back, although I can't imagine what. It would have to be something that stays with the pushback tractor, and when the tractor operator removes it, he/she would have to hold it up and get a thumbs up from the pilot. This is a case where everybody missed a pin with the red REMOVE BEFORE FLIGHT ribbon hanging down, all the way through the push-back. You'd hope that the tug operator or a wing tip escort would notice as a final back stop, but evidently not. Still, the responsibility is with the Capt in the end.

@JohnK all Boeing and Airbus aircraft will be fitted with a bypass pin for pushback! A bypass pin is used during towing or pushback to disengage the aircraft's nose wheel steering, preventing hydraulic pressure from steering the nose wheel. It protects the aircraft's systems during ground handling. The pin, is removed after pushback and shown/waved to the  flight crew by the ground staff.

@tedioustortoise thanks. The RJs used captive pins in the scissors links.  In either case, if they are forgotten you find out right away as you as you try to taxi.
